# running script shell when a new row is creat

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, triggers

I would like to run a script shell when a new row is added to the table in the database. I'm using MySql in ubuntu-server with version 12.04 LTS. I have tried to use "Triggers", but i didn't find solution to call the extern program.

Please, how can I solve this problem and call the script?

Regards

Comment: There was similar question
See [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195894/call-external-script-with-mysql-trigger-whitout-sys-exec-on-ubuntu-armhf

Comment: what have you tryed so far?

Comment: 2 minutes on google: http://www.mysqludf.org/ click on the "sys" repository. Those are UDF functions to be called from a trigger. You will have to "install" them, though...